# How to select a tag inside IDs?

Tags: html, css, firebug

I have a question regarding CSS selectors. First, here is a screenshot:

[image: Firebug screenshot]

This is Firebug showing a DOM tree. Just look at the question mark. Why is this rule getting applied? The selected element is not inside the (single) element with this ID.

The *Style* side panel shows all CSS rules applied to the selected element on the left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commas separate entire selectors.

Your selector means `#SummaryInner td` *or* `th`.